# Use the lib_mysqludf_preg library to replace the first image of every post

Tags: mysql, wordpress, preg-replace

I want to remove the first image of every post of my wordpress blog, so I installed the lib_mysqludf_preg library to use the preg_replace() function that performs a regular expression search and replaces using a PCRE pattern.

Once installed, I have tested it with this line of code to assure that everything works fine:

```
SELECT PREG_REPLACE('/fox/i' , '' ,  'the quick brown fox' ,2 );
```

The result was as expected, so the installation is OK.

The problem is that I don't know how to use this function to replace the images that are stored in the column 'content_post' (at 'wordpress.wp_posts') for a blank space. I tried this expression:

```
SELECT PREG_REPLACE('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', post_content, 1) FROM wordpress.wp_posts;
```

But this code returns me the whole lists of posts, not only of this database but of the rest of the databases I have installed in my local computer and doesn't replace any single image.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved the problem. I post the code because it may be of use for someone with a similar doubt.

This is the code I have used:

```
UPDATE database_name.wp_posts
SET post_content=PREG_REPLACE( '/<img[^>]+\>/i', '' , post_content, 1 );
```